# Why does length of Signatures in two certificates using same Signature Algorithm sha256WithRSAEncryption is different?

Tags: certificates, digital-signature, rsa

I have this recent Wikipedia certificate issued by intermediate CA Let's encrypt:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            03:95:2f:46:69:de:e4:d2:19:35:7f:f0:27:6a:fa:fe:09:cb
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption

...
...
...
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         8f:3d:83:cb:3d:f9:40:4d:cb:c4:65:6b:f0:46:1d:14:55:c9:
         56:c6:32:f6:53:31:2b:15:ab:33:d2:9c:12:9b:cd:80:cc:e5:
         d9:ef:1c:42:9b:56:24:6a:ee:47:df:21:68:4e:2a:d7:b2:6b:
         6f:ef:2d:67:8a:27:b2:04:e3:03:04:f9:30:d1:b0:6c:b7:5a:
         87:f8:59:58:89:b2:f0:8c:1e:34:4d:01:79:5e:e1:1d:01:77:
         69:39:07:58:5e:66:a2:ea:a1:c0:98:ef:8b:ae:f2:28:59:cf:
         72:10:33:60:8f:5c:4d:b5:d8:92:94:c0:c5:63:73:90:76:9f:
         2f:24:29:50:3c:b4:b3:0b:81:79:6f:55:6c:3e:c3:83:bb:dc:
         3a:a8:2e:cc:a7:ed:ff:dc:c8:ad:bf:a9:5b:a5:29:a5:93:20:
         41:75:4b:b8:ef:6d:49:8e:55:93:91:1c:a4:e2:5b:24:af:21:
         3d:37:e8:84:82:07:84:82:6c:39:fc:e7:c8:cb:34:eb:1d:8f:
         22:5f:45:5f:77:2a:05:19:21:be:81:00:52:28:37:67:1a:50:
         a7:94:e3:bf:7b:bc:0d:a3:01:f9:77:e6:f9:a9:c2:9c:2d:4c:
         37:da:90:2f:8b:9d:27:dd:5c:fe:73:32:22:d3:1b:d2:ab:9c:
         73:fe:b5:ff
```

In this certificate, you can see the `Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption` and the Signature below it. The size of the signature is 256 bytes.

Also, I have the certificate of intermediary CA (Let's encrypt):

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            91:2b:08:4a:cf:0c:18:a7:53:f6:d6:2e:25:a7:5f:5a
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
...
...
...

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         85:ca:4e:47:3e:a3:f7:85:44:85:bc:d5:67:78:b2:98:63:ad:
         75:4d:1e:96:3d:33:65:72:54:2d:81:a0:ea:c3:ed:f8:20:bf:
         5f:cc:b7:70:00:b7:6e:3b:f6:5e:94:de:e4:20:9f:a6:ef:8b:
         b2:03:e7:a2:b5:16:3c:91:ce:b4:ed:39:02:e7:7c:25:8a:47:
         e6:65:6e:3f:46:f4:d9:f0:ce:94:2b:ee:54:ce:12:bc:8c:27:
         4b:b8:c1:98:2f:a2:af:cd:71:91:4a:08:b7:c8:b8:23:7b:04:
         2d:08:f9:08:57:3e:83:d9:04:33:0a:47:21:78:09:82:27:c3:
         2a:c8:9b:b9:ce:5c:f2:64:c8:c0:be:79:c0:4f:8e:6d:44:0c:
         5e:92:bb:2e:f7:8b:10:e1:e8:1d:44:29:db:59:20:ed:63:b9:
         21:f8:12:26:94:93:57:a0:1d:65:04:c1:0a:22:ae:10:0d:43:
         97:a1:18:1f:7e:e0:e0:86:37:b5:5a:b1:bd:30:bf:87:6e:2b:
         2a:ff:21:4e:1b:05:c3:f5:18:97:f0:5e:ac:c3:a5:b8:6a:f0:
         2e:bc:3b:33:b9:ee:4b:de:cc:fc:e4:af:84:0b:86:3f:c0:55:
         43:36:f6:68:e1:36:17:6a:8e:99:d1:ff:a5:40:a7:34:b7:c0:
         d0:63:39:35:39:75:6e:f2:ba:76:c8:93:02:e9:a9:4b:6c:17:
         ce:0c:02:d9:bd:81:fb:9f:b7:68:d4:06:65:b3:82:3d:77:53:
         f8:8e:79:03:ad:0a:31:07:75:2a:43:d8:55:97:72:c4:29:0e:
         f7:c4:5d:4e:c8:ae:46:84:30:d7:f2:85:5f:18:a1:79:bb:e7:
         5e:70:8b:07:e1:86:93:c3:b9:8f:dc:61:71:25:2a:af:df:ed:
         25:50:52:68:8b:92:dc:e5:d6:b5:e3:da:7d:d0:87:6c:84:21:
         31:ae:82:f5:fb:b9:ab:c8:89:17:3d:e1:4c:e5:38:0e:f6:bd:
         2b:bd:96:81:14:eb:d5:db:3d:20:a7:7e:59:d3:e2:f8:58:f9:
         5b:b8:48:cd:fe:5c:4f:16:29:fe:1e:55:23:af:c8:11:b0:8d:
         ea:7c:93:90:17:2f:fd:ac:a2:09:47:46:3f:f0:e9:b0:b7:ff:
         28:4d:68:32:d6:67:5e:1e:69:a3:93:b8:f5:9d:8b:2f:0b:d2:
         52:43:a6:6f:32:57:65:4d:32:81:df:38:53:85:5d:7e:5d:66:
         29:ea:b8:dd:e4:95:b5:cd:b5:56:12:42:cd:c4:4e:c6:25:38:
         44:50:6d:ec:ce:00:55:18:fe:e9:49:64:d4:4e:ca:97:9c:b4:
         5b:c0:73:a8:ab:b8:47:c2
```

Here in the CA's certificate, you can see the `Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption`, same as Wikipedia's certificate signature but the Signature below it is of 512 bytes.

If I understand correctly the signature generation process for this case, it is going to be like - encrypt(SHA256(Certificate content)), where SHA256(Certificate content) would be of the same size for the Wikipedia certificate and Let's encrypt certificate. What I don't understand is how the length of encryption of the same size of data results in different sizes?

Comment: https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp

Comment: https://lapo.it/asn1js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of an RSA signature (or ciphertext) is the length of the key. The first certificate above is signed using a 2048 bit (256 byte) RSA key, and the second one is signed using a 4096 bit (512 byte) RSA key.

---

Also note that, despite the name, "sha256WithRSAEncryption" isn't properly encryption. Although it happens to be true for RSA in particular that the mathematical operation used to encrypt is also the one used to sign (just with the private key instead of the public one), there are security-relevant considerations for encryption that aren't relevant for signing, and vice versa. Plus, by convention, private keys *can't* be used for encryption. Many other public key algorithms exist, and support signing with their private keys, but mostly do not have the "sign is the same mathematical process as encrypt" property (and indeed many don't support encryption at all).

Comment: In particular the leaf cert is signed using the key of the intermediate CA LetsEncrypt R3, which is 2048, but the intermediate CA's cert is signed using the key of the root ISRG Root CA X1, which is 4096. The unfortunate names of the OIDs for what are now RSASSA-PKCS1v1_5 signature schemes were set around 1990 before people fully appreciated the important separation between signing and encyption, and once baked into implementations became very hard to change.